# Add reference to lookup table, insert in lookup if needed

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to know if there is a more elegant way (and better efficiency) to deal with a lookup table.

Say I have a table ITEM(i_id, i_name,...) a table KEYWORD (k_id, k_name,...) and a table to link them ITEM_KEYWORD(i_id, k_id).

A user is adding/updating an item and they are adding several keywords(free text on the form). I would do in PHP...

```
foreach (keyword being added)
    SQL to find keyword in KEYWORD table
    if found we have the k_id
    if not, we SQL insert into KEYWORD table and get the new k_id
    now we can run an SQL to insert into ITEM_KEYWORD the i_id and k_id
```

That's up to 3 SQL queries per keyword added. Does anyone have a better way to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
// foreach
$this->db->query("
INSERT INTO KEYWORD (keyword)
VALUES ('hello')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE k_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(k_id)
");

$kid = $this->db->insert_id();
```

If you have the column `k_id` set to index `PRIMARY` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `keyword` as UNIQUE, there's only a need for this one (two counting insert_id) query. Either it doesn't exist and is INSERTED, else it just does a dummy update, but regardless it return the `k_id`.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html#c8755)

Answer (score 0):

Do all your look ups first and then test against them somehow.

```
array keywords from query: 
  SELECT id,name from KEYWORD WHERE KEYWORD.name IN (list of keywords being added)

new = array_diff(keywords_to_add, keywords)

insert: INSERT INTO keyword (name) VALUES ( values of new keywords as multi-insert)

for each keyword being added:

INSERT INTO ITEM_KEYWORD i_id, k_id VALUES (?, (SELECT id FROM KEYWORD WHERE KEYWORD.name = ?))
```